# Paste two files into one using Linux

Tags: paste

I was trying to paste two files into one in Linux:

> file1

```
1 101 0 0 0 -9
1 102 0 0 0 -9
1 103 0 0 0 -9
1 104 0 0 0 -9
1 105 0 0 0 -9
1 106 0 0 0 -9
1 107 0 0 0 -9
1 108 0 0 0 -9
1 109 0 0 0 -9
1 110 0 0 0 -9
```

> file2:

```
2 2 1 3 1 3 3 3 1 3 1 1 1 3 1 2 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 2 1 
1 2 3 3 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 1 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 
2 2 1 3 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 2 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 2 1 
1 2 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 
1 2 1 3 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 2 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 1 3 
1 2 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 
2 2 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 
1 2 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 
2 2 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 
1 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 3
```

I have tried `paste -d " " file1 file2 > output` and `paste file file2 | sed 's/\t/ /' > file3` but for some reason did not do it. I am getting only the content of file2 in output.

The desired out put is:

```
1 101 0 0 0 -9 2 2 1 3 1 3 3 3 1 3 1 1 1 3 1 2 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 2 1            
1 102 0 0 0 -9 1 2 3 3 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 1 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1            
1 103 0 0 0 -9 2 2 1 3 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 2 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 2 1            
1 104 0 0 0 -9 1 2 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1            
1 105 0 0 0 -9 1 2 1 3 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 2 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 1 3            
1 106 0 0 0 -9 1 2 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1            
1 107 0 0 0 -9 2 2 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1            
1 108 0 0 0 -9 1 2 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1            
1 109 0 0 0 -9 2 2 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1            
1 110 0 0 0 -9 1 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 3
```

Please note, with `less output` I am getting the two files joined, but with `^M` between them.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: How are you viewing the output?

Comment: more or less fileNmae

Comment: with less I see the files are joined, but instead of space I have ^M

Comment: 1 101 0 0 0 -9^M 2 2 1 3

Comment: Your comment _"but instead of space I have ^M"_ is critical to answering your question — you should edit your question and add that information.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! I just noticed this and I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file1 has CRLF line endings. Use `dos2unix` to remove the CRs and get the expected output.